# Mysql query latest before date or (if empty then) first after

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to retrieve an entry with the latest date before a given date, and if it doesn't exist then take the soonest after that given date.

I tried googling it, but I couldn't find this scenario

Comment: Add your table definition (as `create table`) some sample data (formatted text or even better as `insert` statements) and the expected output (as formatted text) based on that sample data

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (datecol < @date) desc,
         (case when datecol < @date then datecol end) desc,
         datecol asc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

for latest before given date -

```
select * from table where date_column<given_date order by date_column desc limit 1
```

now check the result if no row return then execute following query for soonest after given date -

```
select * from table where date_column>given_date order by date_column limit 1
```